# woocommerce payment plugin adding tax detail on checkout page

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to add payment plugin to woocommerce.I am very new on woocommerce.

I followed this plugin example : https://github.com/wp-plugins/woocommerce-payment-gateway/blob/b1d2a53ea1a71aaa6eb404af1efd2148afe2b257/gateway-inspire.php

When user write credit card first 6 number I want to show tax details on checkout page.I am calling service for taking taxes. Here is my related checkout page:

[image]

I am confusing about that how can I show tax details when first 6 digits is on input.

What is true way for showing tax? I didnot find any example like this.

I am sory for bad English.

Thanks in advance.